# app in wampserver become slow or crash when internet connection is not stable

Tags: performance, wampserver, lan

I have a PHP web application installed on local network, I have added

> "require all granted"

in httpd.conf
also, I have added

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1      127.0.0.1
```

on c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
also

> skip_name_resolve

on my.ini ([mysqld])

but always the app sometimes crash and need to restart apache and sometimes become very slow when internet connection no stable

I have also disabled LMHOTS in server PC

but the problem is still not solved

*******EDIT********

in other words
in local network,

when internet connection  is ok, all PCs on local network work well, but when it is down, only the server can access web app and other PCs crash and need to restart wampserver to be connected

Comment: Host file should be _Line 1_ `127.0.0.1 localhost` and _Line2_ `::1 localhost`

Comment: Are you accessing the site from the internet or from the PC running WAMPServer

Comment: from the pc running wampserver